# Discord.js Toggle Commands On Multible Servers

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So i want a discord bot were you can **toggle** commands on the server the command was writen in. Just for an example:

```
if(cmd === "me"){
    message.channel.send(`You <@${message.author.id}>!`);
}
```

To toggle the command on/of on any server you would need to write "*me on*" or "*me off* ". "*me on*" Will allow to execute the command on that server and "*me off* " will not allow the command to be executed on that server. I would like this to work on many servers so no allow on guild etc.

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of guilds and if they are on or off.

First start by initializing all guilds

```js
var guilds = [];
var commands = ['me', 'test']; //List of all commands that can be toggled
bot.on('ready', () => {
   guilds = bot.guilds.map(guild => {  //For each guild create an object of bools based on the commands
      var obj = {};
      commands.forEach(command => obj[command] = true);
      return {
         toggles: obj,
         id: guild.id
      };
   });
});
```

we now have a data structure that looks like

```
[
  {
    id: (guildId)
    toggles: {me: true, test: true}
  }
]
```

Now whenever we get a message its super simple to check if the command is active

```
bot.on('message', msg => {
   var cmd = ;//get command from msg
   var guildToggles = guilds.find(guild => guild.id == msg.guild.id);
   if(guildToggles.toggles[cmd]){
      //Command is active. Run
   }else{
      //Command is not active. Dont run
   }
});
```

Toggling commands is super easy as well. Basically just have to do `guildToggles.toggles[cmd] = !guildToggles.toggles[cmd]`

Comment: Thanks for the answer @strikee ! I just dont really get it rn. Im not able to write "me off" in the discord server to disable the command right? Or am i just thinking wrong?

Comment: What i posted is not the entire system. You see need to add in the logic to toggle the commands. I recommend an approach like "turnoff [command]". Then you can do something like ``commandToTurnOff = message.content.split(' ')[0]`` then use the code I posted above to actually change the value of the toggle

Comment: Hi again @strikee ! Another question... I cant really get this to work, it seems like it won't toggle. Could you write an example command that i can look on and try to wrap my head around it? Im sorry for the questions, i just really want to know how this works and i think it's verry fun. Even though im not that good on it. Thanks

Comment: The script I posted was simply showing how to format a possible data structure you can use. You need to write the actual code that will update the values within the data structure.